# Field error when Grails 3 domain object with column rename is saved

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have been porting my social network, www.nderground.net, from Grails 2 to Grails 3. There seem to be subtle differences in the way Grails domain classes/GORM work from Grails 2 to Grails 3.

The nderground code uses a domain class named "Invitation" to save information about invitations that have been sent by email to nderground. The domain class and it's associated constraints and mapping are included below.

The "host" field is the User object for the person who is "hosting" the invitation. This field is mapping into the database field "handle" in the static mapping.

When I save an Invitation object with Grails 3 (but not Grails 2) I get the following error:

```
Field error in object 'nderground.Invitation' on field 'host': rejected value [InvitationUser]; codes [nderground.Invitation.host.unique.error.nderground.Invitation.host,nderground.Invitation.host.unique.error.host,nderground.Invitation.host.unique.error.nderground.User,nderground.Invitation.host.unique.error,invitation.host.unique.error.nderground.Invitation.host,invitation.host.unique.error.host,invitation.host.unique.error.nderground.User,...
```

It seems like "host" is not being mapped to the "handle" column in the Postgres table.

```
class Invitation {
public enum InvitationType {
    BY_EMAIL,         // invitation was sent by email
    PASSWORD_RESET,   // invitation was sent for a password reset
    REQUESTED_INVITE, // an invitation that is requested via the www.nderground.net/ page. May be open or accepted.
    REQUESTED_CLOSED, // the requested invitation has expired
    OPEN              // the invitation is open - a matching email address in not required
}

User host // person issuing the invitation
String inviteEmail // email address for the invitee
Date inviteDate    // date the invitation was issued
Date expireDate    // date the invitation expires 
String inviteCode  // invitation code (sent to the invitee via email)
boolean accepted   // true - the invitation was accepted, false it was not
boolean makeConnection // true - connect to the invitation host, false - don't connect
InvitationType type = InvitationType.BY_EMAIL // Invitation type

static constraints = {
    host nullable : false, unique: false
    inviteEmail email: true, blank: false, nullable: false
    inviteDate nullable: false
    expireDate nullable: false
    inviteCode blank: false, nullable: false
    type blank: false
}

static mapping = {
    host column : 'handle'
    inviteCode index : 'Invite_Code_Ix'
    inviteCode unique : 'inviteEmail' // invite code and email are unique
    accepted defaultValue: false
    makeConnection defaultValue: true
    type enumType: 'ordinal'
}
```

}

The Postgres table is shown below. The "handle" column in the Postgres table should be mapped to the "host" field in the domain class (again, this works with Grails 2, but, apparently, not with Grails 3).

```
CREATE TABLE invitation
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  version bigint NOT NULL,
  accepted boolean NOT NULL,
  expire_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  handle bigint NOT NULL,
  invite_code character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  invite_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  invite_email character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  make_connection boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
  type integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT invitation_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk94psn3lk2xu0l5gl71ayfm4ht FOREIGN KEY (handle)
      REFERENCES users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_krm2ne7yedxtul61k5wdvjaqw FOREIGN KEY (handle)
      REFERENCES users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT uk26487c1809285677f20d7df5c6dc UNIQUE (invite_email, invite_code),
  CONSTRAINT uk_s57hvf05ru6s0e2hyoorefmlf UNIQUE (invite_code)
)
```

Any suggestions in how to fix this?  I could remove the column name mapping, but this is supposed to work in Grails 3. Is there something I'm doing wrong or is this a Grails 3 bug? (I am using Grails 3.3.1).

Comment: Why do you have `unique: false` in your constraints for `host`?

Comment: The unique:false constraint on the host column seems to have been causing the problem. I no longer get a database error on the save operation. Using this unique constraint in the Domain class was unnecessary, but it still seems like it should not have caused the problem.

Comment: Possibly a bug related to `unique: false`.  It wouldn't surprise me if that would go unnoticed because there is no reason to ever express `unique: false`.